# IIS complains about "<%@ Page Async="true" %>" once Visual Studio 2019 is installed

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asynchronous, model-view-controller

We are facing a very odd issue on a old ASP.NET application that has been running fine since years.
Since we have installed Visual Studio 2019, the Web page dos not open properly and the process w3wp.exe crashes with the following errors :
(sorry the system is in french :))

---

Application : w3wp.exe
Version du Framework : v4.0.30319
Description : le processus a été arrêté en raison d'une exception non gérée.
Informations sur l'exception : System.InvalidOperationException
à System.Web.AspNetSynchronizationContext.OperationStarted()
à System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ThreadBehavior.BindCore(System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc ByRef, Boolean)
à System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc ByRef)

Informations sur l'exception : System.Runtime.FatalException
à System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc ByRef)
à System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc ByRef)
à System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean)
à System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.DispatchAndReleasePump(System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestContext, Boolean, System.ServiceModel.OperationContext)
...

---

---

Une exception non gérée s'est produite et le processus a été arrêté.

Application ID: /LM/W3SVC/3/ROOT

Process ID: 236

Exception: System.Runtime.FatalException

Message: Impossible de démarrer une opération asynchrone pour le moment. Les opérations asynchrones peuvent être démarrées uniquement depuis un gestionnaire ou un module asynchrone, ou lors de certains événements du cycle de vie de la page. Si cette exception a été levée durant l'exécution d'une page, vérifiez que celle-ci est marquée de la façon suivante : <%@ Page Async="true" %>. Cette exception peut aussi indiquer une tentative d'appeler une méthode « async void », qui n'est pas généralement pris en charge au sein de traitement d'une demande ASP.NET. À la place, la méthode asynchrone doit retourner une tâche, et l'appelant doit l'attendre.

StackTrace:    à System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc& rpc)
à System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)
à System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc& rpc)
à System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc& rpc)
...

---

As soon as I uninstall Visual Studio 2019 the web site is working fine again.
I understand the error and I guess we could rewrite the code to fullfill this "Async" restrictions but that does not explain why the error only occurs on the system when Visual Studio is installed.

Any suggestion to understand the real cause of this issue would be very welcome !!!

Thanks